# understanding key value coding document example

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa

```
    - (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableview

  objectValueForTableColumn:(id)column

                        row:(int)row

     {

ChildObject *child = [childrenArray objectAtIndex:row];

if ( [[column identifier] isEqualToString:@"name"] ) {

    return [child name];

}

if ( [[column identifier] isEqualToString:@"age"] ) {

    return [child age];

}
     ......
```

The code above is from this page:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Overview.html

I am unable to understand what [child name] is.
Is the instance variable of ChildObject class being sent a message "name" which is somehow supposed to bring up a name from an array object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[child name]` sends a message called "name" to `child` which is an instance of the ChildObject class. The ChildObject class implements a method named `name`, which (presumably) returns an NSString whose value is equal to the value of child's name instance variable. The only way an array object is involved is that `child` itself is obtained by pulling it from `childrenArray` which is an array of ChildObject instances.